# Cocoapods error when installing libraries

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby-on-rails, cocoapods

I'm trying to install dependencies via cocoapods. I use command "pod install" and it throws error . Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "Passport" do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
    pod 'MagicalRecord', '2.2'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~>0.8'
    pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.3'
    pod 'MMDrawerController-Storyboard', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard/1.0.0/MMDrawerController-    Storyboard.podspec'
    pod 'PMCalendar', '~> 0.3.2'
    pod 'TNRadioButtonGroup', '0.2'
    pod 'WYPopoverController', '~> 0.2.2'
    pod 'AZSocketIO'
    pod 'SocketRocket'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'
   pod 'AttributedMarkdown', :git => 'https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown.git'
end

class Pod::Podfile
    def self.MR_preprocessor_definitions(installer)
    target = installer.project.targets.find{|t| t.to_s == "Pods-Passport-MagicalRecord"}
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    s = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
    s = [ '$(inherited)' ] if s == nil;
    s.push('MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING=0') if config.to_s == "Debug";
    s.push('MR_SHORTHAND');
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = s
end
end
end

post_install do |installer|
    Pod::Podfile::MR_preprocessor_definitions(installer)
end
```

Here is the error:
[image]
Please help me solve

Comment: Try "sudo pod install"

Comment: It doesn't help, do you have another solution?